# Spliting a path column in python

Tags: python, pandas, split

Hi I have a column with path like this:

`path_column = ['C:/Users/Desktop/sample\\1994-QTR1.tsv','C:/Users/Desktop/sample\\1995-QTR1.tsv']`

I need to split and get just the file name.

### Expected output:

[1994-QTR1,1995-QTR1]

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this:
os.path.basename('/root/file.ext')

Comment: Yes but it did not work as the path is inside a column.

Comment: `path.split("\\")[-1].split(".")[0]` this works

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split' I am getting this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['new'] = df['path'].str.extract(r'\\([^\\]*)\.\w+$', expand=False)
```

The equivalent with [`rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) would be much less efficient:

```
df['new'] = df['path'].str.rsplit('\\', n=1).str[-1].str.rsplit('.', n=1).str[0]
```

Output:

```
                                    path        new
0  C:/Users/Desktop/sample\1994-QTR1.tsv  1994-QTR1
1  C:/Users/Desktop/sample\1995-QTR1.tsv  1995-QTR1
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1Qqyzx/1)

Comment: @kiranu I added a solution with `rsplit`, but `extract` will be more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Use this or you can use regex to match and take what you want.

```
path.split("\\")[-1].split(".")[0]
```

Output:

```
'1994-QTR1'
```

**Edit**

```
new_col=[]
for i in path_column:
    new_col.append(i.split("\\")[-1].split(".")[0])
print (new_col)
```

**NOTE:** If you need it in a list, you can append it to a new list from the loop.

Output:

```
['1994-QTR1', '1995-QTR1']
```

Comment: Since its a series I am not able to use split function

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to the above, but you don't need to declare the separator.

```
import os

path = "C:/Users/Desktop/sample\\1994-QTR1.tsv"
name = path.split(os.path.sep)[-1]
print(name)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might harness [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) for this task following way

```
import pathlib
import pandas as pd
def get_stem(path):
    return pathlib.PureWindowsPath(path).stem
df = pd.DataFrame({'paths':['C:/Users/Desktop/sample\\1994-QTR1.tsv','C:/Users/Desktop/sample\\1994-QTR2.tsv','C:/Users/Desktop/sample\\1994-QTR3.tsv']})
df['names'] = df.paths.apply(get_stem)
print(df)
```

gives output

```
                                   paths      names
0  C:/Users/Desktop/sample\1994-QTR1.tsv  1994-QTR1
1  C:/Users/Desktop/sample\1994-QTR2.tsv  1994-QTR2
2  C:/Users/Desktop/sample\1994-QTR3.tsv  1994-QTR3
```